# opencv FLANN radiusSearch give bad results

Tags: c++, opencv, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I'd like to do radius search to find all valid neighbors, but it seems to give me wrong results. Here is my code

```
#include "opencv/cv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    // create a group of points
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;
    points.emplace_back(438.6, 268.8);
    points.emplace_back(439.1, 268.6);
    points.emplace_back(438.2, 268.1);
    points.emplace_back(498.3, 285.9);
    points.emplace_back(312.9, 245.9);
    points.emplace_back(313.4, 245.7);
    points.emplace_back(313.1, 245.5);
    points.emplace_back(312.5, 245.4);
    points.emplace_back(297.6, 388.1);
    points.emplace_back(291.7, 309.8);
    points.emplace_back(194.1, 369.8);
    points.emplace_back(439.9, 314.9);
    points.emplace_back(312.8, 246.0);

    // create features array
    cv::Mat_<float> features(0, 2);

    for (auto && point : points) {

        //Fill matrix
        cv::Mat row = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 2) << point.x, point.y);
        features.push_back(row);
    }
    std::cout << features << std::endl;

    cv::flann::Index flann_index(features, cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams());
    std::vector<float> query{ 300.6f, 268.8f };
    std::vector<int> ind;
    std::vector<float> d;
    unsigned int max_neighbours = 10;
    // Here I deliberately increase the radius to contain all the points
    double radius = 500.0;
    flann_index.radiusSearch(query, ind, d, radius, max_neighbours,
        cv::flann::SearchParams());
}
```

Output of `ind` is `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, all zeros, which is unexpected.

Anyone knows why?

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= Update

```
int main() {

// create a group of points
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;
points.emplace_back(438.6, 268.8);
points.emplace_back(439.1, 268.6);
points.emplace_back(438.2, 268.1);
points.emplace_back(498.3, 285.9);
points.emplace_back(312.9, 245.9);
points.emplace_back(313.4, 245.7);
points.emplace_back(313.1, 245.5);
points.emplace_back(312.5, 245.4);
points.emplace_back(297.6, 388.1);
points.emplace_back(291.7, 309.8);
points.emplace_back(194.1, 369.8);
points.emplace_back(439.9, 314.9);
points.emplace_back(312.8, 246.0);

// create features array
cv::Mat_<float> features(0, 2);

for (auto && point : points) {

    //Fill matrix
    cv::Mat row = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 2) << point.x, point.y);
    features.push_back(row);
}
std::cout << features << std::endl;

cv::flann::GenericIndex<cvflann::L2<float> > index(features, cvflann::KDTreeIndexParams());
std::vector<float> query(438.6f, 268.8f);
std::vector<int> ind;
std::vector<float> d;
index.radiusSearch(query, ind, d, 45.f, cvflann::SearchParams());
// I can print std::vector by some method, the reader may not, so I comment this line
//std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

As `cv::flann::Index` is deprecated, I change to new API, but this time, the program just doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue, and the solution is that radius must be specified as radius squared (^2). And the length of ind and d will be set by max_neighbors, but the return of radiusSearch must be checked to find out which is less, num_found or max_neighbours;

```
double radius = 500.0;
int num_found = flann_index.radiusSearch(query, ind, d, radius*radius, max_neighbours, cv::flann::SearchParams());
num_found = min(num_found,(int)ind.size()); // check correct size
for(int i=0; i<num_found; i++) { ... ind[i] ... d[i] ... }
```

in my case, i also had to adjust the index and search parameters to return correct results:

```
flann::KDTreeIndexParams indexParams(128);
flann::SearchParams searchParams(1024,0.0,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the example of the plain FLANN I had used [here](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/blob/master/examples/flann_example.cpp), you would see that they call `buildIndex()`, which you don't. Could that be?

Try:

```
cv::flann::Index flann_index(features, cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams());
flann_index.buildIndex();
```

Comment: `cv::flann::Index` is deprecated now. I think a new example code based on new  API should be updated in the example. I will update soon, maybe you can help me to check.

Comment: I have add new code, this time it the program just did not work, it terminated when running.

Comment: Did my answer work for the original question @ted930511?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the size of `ind` and `d`.